# X server doesn't restart

Tags: nvidia, console, xserver, mode

I recently installed nvidia's cuda toolkit in ubuntu 12.04. After restarting the computer, it stays in console mode. When I run sudo service lightdm restart, it gets stuck mid execution and the computer remains in console mode after a forced reboot. What can be done here?

Comment: Are you sure that you have an nVidia GPU which is CUDA capable?

Comment: yes, the gpu is cuda capable. I solved the issue already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the cuda driver (via an nvidia purge command) included in the sdk and using instead the one provided [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

sudo service lightdm restart worked fine then.